# Body tag automatically add horizontal scrolling when table has horizontal scroll and body has vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, angular

I am facing an issue regarding the horizontal scroll.

[image]

As you can see above pic page has 2 horizontal scrolls first one is for a table scroll and the second one is page scroll that is automatically added, now I don't want the second scroll on the page.

How can I achieve this? I can't use overflow-x: hidden as in some other screen I need body overflow-x: scroll.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-x:auto` to the `parent` of your `scroll element`.

```css
.container{
  background-color:yellow;
  overflow-x:auto;
  
}
.tab{
  width:120vw;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">Your Tabels</div>
</div>
```

And if it did not help, add `overflow-x:none` to your `body` Element

Comment: not working as the scroll is for the body element and as I mentioned in my post I can't set overflow-x into body.

Comment: @JayPatel: If your "scroll Elements" dont have a parent, try to add one and set its overflow-x to auto. Do not add overflow-x to your body

Comment: there are two scrolls, one is the body scroll and the second is the table scroll has a parent with overflow-x: auto, So I am a bit confused about where should I add that scroll eminent.

Comment: what I mean is: add overflow-x: auto to the Parent of your Tabel where you want to scroll it. and do not add overflow-x: auto to the body Element.

Comment: Exactly did the same bro but still showing a horizontal scroll, and the interesting thing is the body tag has a horizontal scroll only, and only it has a vertical scroll.

Comment: is your website online?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247840/discussion-between-jay-patel-and-hamid).